# Solve using Laplace transforms

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I want to solve the PDE 
 
$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=x$$
$$u(x,0)=0, x>0$$
$$u(0,t)=0, t>0$$
for $x>0,t>0$ using a Laplace transform in t.

 I Laplace transform the equation and get
$$xs\hat{u}(x,s)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat{u}(x,s)=\frac{x}{s}$$
where $\hat{u}(x,s)=L(u(x,t))=\int_{t=0}^{\infty} e^{-st}u(x,t)dt$.

 Solving this ODE, I obtain
$$\hat{u}(x,s)=\frac{1}{s^2} + A(s)e^{\frac{-sx^2}{2}}.$$
I then apply the second boundary condition to get
$$\hat{u}(x,s)=\frac{1}{s^2}-\frac{1}{s^2}e^{\frac{-sx^2}{2}}.$$
Now I need to inverse transform to get $u(x,t)$. I know that
$$L^{-1}(\frac{1}{s^2})=t$$
but I don't know how to find
$$L^{-1}(\frac{1}{s^2}e^{\frac{-sx^2}{2}}).$$

Comment: I get $(t-x^2/2)\,u(t-x^2/2),$ where $u$ is the Heaviside step function.

Comment: Use the shift theorem